# Footer overlaps with the content

Tags: css, footer, sticky, sticky-footer

I want the footer to be sticky at the bottom (even if the user zoom out at 25%), when I try to change the position from relative to absolute, but the footer overlaps with the content.

How to fix this? Here's my live [link](http://www.homecredit.ph/financial-literacy/)

CSS:

```
footer #bottom-footer {
    background: url(/files/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you mean is that the content at the bottom of the page is underneath the fixed footer.

One fix is adding the width of the footer amount of padding to the bottom of the footer's parent.

Comment: Why you should use the width of the footer ? When i would use the width on my Browser its nearly 3500px.